# Como accedo a los métodos de mi objecto en un array en Java?

Tags: java, array, herencia, polimorfismo, casting

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Voy a crear un array , supongamos de `animales`, siendo `animales` mi superclass,  ahora, la clase `lagarto` va a heredar de animales y así sucesivamente todos los demás `animales` que vaya a ir agregando.

Mi array lo voy de definir así:

```
animales [] zoo = new animales[50];
```

Quiero poder almacenar en él, distintos animales, todos ellos van a heredar de la clase `animales`.

Si quiero llamar a un método en especifico de mi clase `lagarto`, por ejemplo `esconderse()`, que es un método que solo la clase `lagarto` implementa, seria así:

```
zoo[5].esconderse();
```

Suponiendo claro, que mi objeto lagarto se encuentra en la posición 5 del array.

¿Por qué no funciona?, al escribir el punto, solo me aparecen los métodos de la clase padre, en mi caso de la clase `animales`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla sería :

```
Lagarto lagarto = (Lagargo)animal[5];
lagarto.esconderse();
```

Porque si los demás animales no se pueden esconder requieres convertir tu animal a uno que si pueda. Pero esta opción sería muy limitada y no reusable.

Puedes hacer un método:

```
void esconder(Animal animal) {
     if (animal instanceof Lagarto) {
         ((Lagarto)animal).esconderse();
}
```

O puedes definir una interface Esconderse:

```
public interface Esconderse {
   public void esconderse();
}
```

Entonces ahora varios animales podrán esconderse si implementan esta interface.

Y puedes cambiar el método esconderse:

```
void esconder(Animal animal) {
     if (animal instanceof Esconderse) {
         ((Esconderse)animal).esconderse();
}
```

Así no limitas a que solo el lagarto se esconda.

Comment: gracias, ya lo entendí.En mi caso, el array es de puros animales, este no tiene idea de que animales contiene, solo sabe que son animales y hasta ahi. Cuando quiera llamar a un método de un animal en especifico, debo primero verificar que sea del tipo correcto, después hace un casting (animal->cocodrilo) y ahora si ya "sabe" el array que en ese lugar hay un cocodrilo, mi pregunta ahora es, si ya hice el casting una vez, si vuelvo a llamarlo, es necesario volver hacer el casting?

Comment: Tendría que ver como lo quieres usar. Puedes guardar ese lagarto en un lugar para poderlo volver a accesar. Pero así como preguntas no sabría decirte.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `animales [] zoo = new animales[50];` declara un arreglo de `animales`, el cual es un objeto que no contiene el método  `esconderse()`.

Asumiendo que tus clases son algo así:

```java
  public class EjemploAnimales
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("HelloWorld!");

      Animal[] zoo = new Animal[5];

      zoo[0] = new Lagarto("Lagartija");
      //Agregar mas animales en el zoo;
      zoo[0].esconderse();

    }
  }


   class Animal{
    public String nombre;

    public Animal(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre(){return nombre;}
    public void setNombre(String nombre){this.nombre = nombre;}
  }

   class Lagarto extends Animal {

    public Lagarto(String nombre){
        super(nombre);
    }

    public String getNombre(){return nombre;}
    public void setNombre(String nombre){this.nombre = nombre;}

    public void esconderse(){ System.out.println( this.nombre + "se esconde"); };
  }
```

No va a funcionar porque zoo[5] puede contener solo `Animales`, lo que tienes que hacer es decirle a tu programa que el elemento en `zoo[5]` es de la clase `Lagarto`.

Puedes comprobar que el objeto pertenezca a la clase Lagarto y luego castear tu objeto `zoo[5]` a la clase `Lagarto` y así ejecutar los métodos de la clase `Lagarto`

```
if (zoo[5] instanceof Lagarto) { 
    ((Lagarto)zoo[5]).esconderse();
}
```

---

El código de este ejemplo queda algo así:

```java
  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("HelloWorld!");

      Animal[] zoo = new Animal[5];

      zoo[0] = new Lagarto("Lagartija");

      if (zoo[0] instanceof Lagarto) { 
           ((Lagarto)zoo[0]).esconderse();
      }

    }
  }


   class Animal{
    public String nombre;

    public Animal(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre(){return nombre;}
    public void setNombre(String nombre){this.nombre = nombre;}
  }

   class Lagarto extends Animal {

    public Lagarto(String nombre){
        super(nombre);
    }

    public String getNombre(){return nombre;}
    public void setNombre(String nombre){this.nombre = nombre;}

    public void esconderse(){ System.out.println( this.nombre + " se esconde"); };
  }
```